# Difference between source SRS and target SRS in Raster Warp function

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I am trying to change a raster layer projections from WGS84 to a custom Lambert layer using 'Raster' --> 'Projections' --> 'Warp' function. I have been asked for source SRS and get SRS. what is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

If your raster file has proper CRS information, you can leave out the source SRS.

Sometimes (especially if you have towgs84 datum shifts), it is necessary to set the source SRS different from what is stored inside the file.

And some raster files (like jpg and png) do not have any SRS information, but you might know they are in degrees, so set EPSG:4326 for the source.

Comment: And the target SRS is obviously the reference system I would like to convert the raster to?